# Integral of a periodic function

Tags: calculus, riemann-integration

If $F:\Bbb R\to \Bbb C$ is $2\pi$-periodic and Riemann integrable on $[-\pi, \pi]$, then show that for all $\alpha\in \Bbb R$,
$$\int _{-\pi}^{\pi} F(t)dt=\int_{\alpha-\pi}^{\alpha+\pi} F(t)dt.$$

Comment: Can I suggest that you draw a picture of your favourite periodic function, and then draw the areas represented by the two integrals in your equation. Once you've done this, you'll see it immediately! :)

Comment: I used the sin function and I can see that the areas are the same! Thank you!

Comment: One quick question...how is Riemann integrability applied?

Comment: If the function is not Riemann integrable, then it wouldn't make sense to write down the integrals in the first place!